# How did author do this algebraic manipulation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In some question of differential operator author did this algebraic manipulation without explanation. Can someone explain this?
[image]

Did he do it by *completing the square* or $$(a^3 + b^3) = (a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)$$ ?

Comment: Write $D=(D+1)-1$ and expand.

Comment: What relationship is supposed to hold between the formulas? There is no equals sign visible in your image.

Answer (score 1):

They are not equal as $-1$ satisfies the first equation but not your second equation.You can factor the equation as $(D^2-2D+5)(D+1)$.

Comment: Can there be different values of yp for one equation? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408216/can-there-be-different-values-of-y-p-for-one-equation

Answer (score 1):

It **isn't**!  what you have is not correct, which you could have seen by multiplying out the terms on the right and seeing that they do NOT give the polynomial on the left.

Let $$u= D+ 1\;\text{so}\; D= u- 1.$$  Then $$D^3- D^2+ 3D+ 5= (u- 1)^3- (u- 1)^2+ 3(u- 1)+ 5= u^3- 3u^2+ 3u- 1- u^2+ 2u- 1+ 3u- 3+ 5= u^3- 4u^2+ 8u= (D+ 1)^3+ 3(D+ 1)^2- 4(D+ 1)^2+ 8(D+ 1).$$

Comment: Please start using LaTeX, see this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Almost all of your posts (seven out of 8 answers you posted yesterday!) need heavy editing.

Answer (score 1):

Those two formulas are related, but they are not *equal* to each other.

The second expression comes from the first one by *substituting* the sub-expression $D+1$ for $D$ in the first expression. They would be equal if $D+1=D$, but of course this is not the case, even for differential operators. (Yes, it is possible for $(D+1)f=Df$, but that does not make the operators equal.)

So the "algebraic manipulation" here is substitution, not factoring or such, and the resulting expression is related to the first but does not equal it. Such substitutions are often useful, but not in the way you thought.

Comment: Can there be different values of yp for one equation? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408216/can-there-be-different-values-of-y-p-for-one-equation

Comment: @user3461957: Yes, in fact infinitely many. If you have one $y_p$ you can find any other by adding a $y_c$. In your particular problem your $y_c$ has three dimensions: $c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^x\sin 2x+c_3e^x\cos 2x$, so there are also three dimensions to all the possible $y_p$.

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2B1%29%5E3-%28x%2B1%29%5E2%2B3%28x%2B1%29%2B5-x%5E3%2Bx%5E2-3x-5) gets that they are not equal as polynomials, with difference $3D^2+D+3$.  Some argument involving the differential operator or the specific problem is needed.

Comment: Can there be different values of yp for one equation? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408216/can-there-be-different-values-of-y-p-for-one-equation